# Finite Group with $n$-automorphism map

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

If $G$ is a finite group and $\phi(x) = x^{p+1}$ is an automorphism of $G$  with $order(\phi) |p$ then $G$ is a $p$-group...?

If the order of $\phi$ is $1$ then $\phi(x) = x = x^{p+1} = x^px \rightarrow x^p =e$ so the order $\forall x\in G$ is $p$ therefore $G$ is a $p$-group

I'm having trouble when considering that the order of $\phi$ is $p$

If the order of $\phi$ is $p$ then

$\phi^p(x) =x= x^{(p+1)^p}$

using the binomial theorem, I get

$\forall x \in G \, \, \, order(x) | \ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k}p^k = (p+1)^p-1$

At first, I thought that the only divisors of this was powers $p$ so I got this:

Suppose for contradiction that $G$ is not a $p$-group. Let $|G| = kp^n$ where $k$ is not a multiple of $p$  ($p\nmid k$). If $k>1$ then take a $q$ in $k$'s prime factorization. So we have $q|k$ and by Cauchy's Theorem $\exists y \in G$ with $y^q = e$ i.e $order(y) = q$.

Since  $\forall x \in G \, \, \, order(x) | \ \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k}p^k$ we must have that $q|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^p \binom{p}{k}p^k$. A contradiction, therefore $k=1$ thus $G$ is a $p$-group.

But through examples, the divisors of $(p+1)^p-1$ also include other primes :'(.  How can I  show $G$ is a $p$-group?

Thanks so much :D

**Update:**

Taking the advice from the comments, Assume every proper subgroup of $G$ is a $p$-group, now take the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, say $P$ then $P$ is normal since it is characteristic i.e $\phi(P) = P$. Since $P$ is a normal Sylow subgroup, it contains all $p$ subgroups of $G$ therefore $P$ contains all subgroups of $G$.

Can I conclude that $P=G$ since $P$ contains all subgroups of $G$?

Comment: Hint: Every subgroup of $G$ is $\phi$ invariant. You can assume by induction that every proper subgroup of $G$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: @abe: that is called induction

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is obsolete.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar There is a difference between off topic and obsolete! I don't think this question should be closed.

Comment: There was no good reason, as far as I can tell, to close this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/823130/6) is false. Let $G$ be cyclic of order 7, and let $p=3$. Then $\phi:G \to G : g \mapsto g^4$ is an automorphism of order 3.

**Update:** The question has been changed now. You can read the original version here: https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/823130/6

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it was wrong. -_-

Comment: Jack: I know your a very knowledgeable person, but have you read the question carefully? The OP is asking that there is a nontrivial inner automorphism $axa^{-1}$ that acts like $x\mapsto x^{p+1}$. This smells like a semidirect product $(\Bbb Z_{p^2}\rtimes \Bbb Z_p$ using thr apropriate automorphism that gives the presentation $$\langle x,y\mid x^{p^2}=1,y^p=1,[y,x]=x^p\rangle$$ or something of the sort. Maybe the question is missing some hypotheses.

Comment: @Pedro: the question has changed dramatically since my (correct) answer was posted.

Comment: (For what is worth, I haven't read the question that carefully, but that is what I got from the scan!)

Comment: @JackSchmidt Oh, my bad then. Let me see past edits. You can always call out on the OP to avoid these kind of misunderstandings! =)

Comment: I answered this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/823130/6 [ basically, the same idea, but $\theta=\phi$ need not be inner ]

Comment: If the question has been substantially changed, you should roll it back to a previous version, I think.

Comment: +Sorry about changing it

Comment: I erased the new one now...

Comment: @abe: no, you should leave this question as it was when I answered it fully, and use the new question to ask the question you now want

Comment: Ok, how can i copy the old version?