# Show finite group is $p$-group given some structure of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, p-groups, pro-p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. If  there exists an $a\in G$ not equal to the identity such that for all $x\in G$,$\phi(x) = axa^{-1}=x^{p+1} $ is an automorphism of $G$ then $G$ is a $p$-group.

This is what I have so for.

The order of $a$ is $p$ since $\phi(a) = a= a^pa\rightarrow a^p=e$ therefore the $order(\phi)|p$

If $order(\phi) = 1$ then for all $ x\in G$ $\phi(x) = x=x^{p+1}\rightarrow x^p=e$ . Thus every element has order $p$ therefore $G$ is a $p-group$

For $order(\phi) = p$ I get stuck:

$\phi^p(x) = x = x^{(p+1)^p}$ using the expansion formula and simplifying i reach that the order of each element in $G$ divides $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{p}{k}p^k=(p+1)^p-1$. But other primes divide this so I can't easily conclude $G$ is a $p$-group.

I proceeded by contradiction:

Suppose for contradiction that $G$ is not a $p$-group. Let $|G| = kp^n$ where $k$ is not a multiple of $p$  ($p\nmid k$). If $k>1$ then take a $q$ in $k$'s prime factorization. So we have $q|k$ and by Cauchy's Theorem $\exists y \in G$ with $y^q = e$ i.e $order(y) = q$.

If $q<p$, applying $\phi$ to $y$ I get that $\langle y\rangle$ has more than $q$ elements since $\phi(y)=y^{p+1}\in \langle y \rangle$ and there are $p$ distint elements achieved by $\phi$

If $p>q$ then....... I cannot reach a contradiction :'(

Question #2: Show each element of $G$ has order $p$

When $order(\phi) = 1$ i get what I want but I'm also stuck when $order(\phi) =p$

I believe $a\in Z(G)$, is there a way I can show this?

Thank you....This is a pretty hard  problem. :'(

Comment: An earlier version of the problem did not mention $\theta$ is an inner-automorphism: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823130/finite-group-with-n-automorphism-map

Comment: Sorry about I thought $axa^{-1}$ was just there to show the order of the automorphism is a divisor of $p$

Comment: It is not a good practice to use quantifiers such as $\forall$ and $\exists$ when writing mathematics. It makes the question harder to read. See http://www.math.harvard.edu/graduate/advise/kleiman.pdf

Comment: :O What! But I took a semester learning this

Comment: Should I not be using $\wedge$ $\neg$...either?

Comment: If there's ambiguity or you're working in formal logic or real analysis where technical exposition is important, it's good to use quantifiers and symbols. But otherwise, being intelligible as possible to your readers generally means just using words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a plan.

Let $N = \{x \in G \mid x^p = 1\}$.

1. Note that $x \in N$ if and only if $x$ commutes with $a$. It follows that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$. It is easy to see that $N$ is characteristic and therefore normal.
2. Take an arbitrary $y \in G$. We have $a y a^{-1} = y^{p+1}$ in $G$. Project this equality onto $G/N$, it gives us $yN = y^{p+1}N$ ($a$ is gone because $a \in N$). Therefore, $y^p \in N$, therefore $y^{p^2} = 1$. This shows that $G$ is a $p$-group, even that the order of each element divides $p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different proof from Dan Shved's:

**Lemma:** In any such group $G$, $a$ normalizes every subgroup, and $a$ lies in every Sylow $p$-subgroup.

> *Proof:* Let $H$ be a subgroup. Then for $x \in H$, $axa^{-1}=x^{p+1} \in H$, so $aHa^{-1} \leq H$; a similar statement holds for $a^{-1}$ and so $H$ is normal. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since $a$ has order $p$ and $a$ normalizes $P$, $\langle a, P \rangle$ is a $p$-group, and so by maximality of $P$, $\langle a, P \rangle = P$ and $a \in P$. $\square$

*Main proof:* Reduce to a minimal counterexample:

> Let $G$ be a group of smallest order such that $G$ has an element $a$ of order $p$ such that for every $x \in G$, $ax=x^{p+1}a$ and yet $G$ is not a $p$-group. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $a$, then $H$ satisfies the same hypothesis. If $H$ is also a proper subgroup, then $H$ is a $p$-group by definition of $G$.

Now consider what this means for an element of prime order $q\neq p$.

> Let $g$ be an element of order $q$ for $q \neq p$. By hypothesis, $a$ normalizes $\langle g \rangle$ so $H=\langle a,g\rangle$ has order $pq$ and satisfies the hypothesis of the problem. If $H <G$ then we have a contradiction, so we must $H=G$ and so $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $pq$.

And show that this structure doesn't satisfy the hypothesis:

> Let $P=\langle a \rangle$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and let $Q=\langle g \rangle$ be a Sylow $q$-subgroup. Since $Q$ is normalized by both $P$ and $Q$, $Q$ is normal in $G$. Since $a$ is contained in every Sylow $p$-subgroup by the lemma, but the Sylow $p$-subgroups have order $p$, we have $P$ is also normal. Hence $G = P \times Q$ is abelian. This a contradiction, since then $aga^{-1} aa^{-1}g = g \neq g^{p+1}$ as $g$ has order $q$ not $p$.

$\square$

Comment: (This proof was based on a higher tech proof: $a$ lies in the Baer kernel of $G$, so is contained in the second center, so centralizes Sylow $q$-subgroups, a contradiction. I tried to get the conclusions using earlier ideas.)

Comment: Thank you so much :D . I wish I can accept two answers. Sorry about yesterday, i must have driven you nuts.